# Javascript changing array values without being told to

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am new to Javascript and therefore this issues may be something simple but I am unable to find an answer.

I have a class Country with a few parameters (i.e. name, area, ppm etc.) as well as a function updateCurrentData(input1, input2) which changes the current values to new ones depending on the inputs. Then, I have a class PPM_Data which has this function:

```
  initialCountries = [];
  copyData = [];

  PPMPerCountryPerYear(year, inputPopulation, inputDeforestation) {
    var result = [];
    this.copyData = this.initialCountries.slice(0);
    console.log(this.copyData);
    console.log(this.initialCountries);

    result.push({2020: this.initialCountries});
    for (let index = 2021; index <= year; index++) {

        this.copyData.forEach(c => {
            c.updateCurrentData(inputPopulation, inputDeforestation);
        })

        let yearData = [];

        this.copyData.forEach(c => {
            yearData.push(c);
        });

        result.push({ [index]: yearData });

    }

    return result;
}
```

The result should return an array with values of each country by year like:

```
{ 2020: Array(12) },
{ 2021: Array(12) }
...
```

where the Array contains each country's data for this year (assume there are 12 countries). Values must change a bit with each year which I guess happens because I get an array with all the years but the Array is the same and it is equal to the last calculation of the loop.

I load the countries's initialCountries from a csv file using d3:

```
loadCountries(path) {
    var self = this;
    var readCsv = d3.csv(path, function (data) {
        var country = new Country(data.name, Number(data.area), Number(data.ppm), Number(data.population), Number(data.population_growth), Number(data.forests_percentage), Number(data.forests_growth));
        self.initialCountries.push(country);
    });

    return readCsv;
}
```

The loadCountries function is called in the componentWillMount() function in App.js.

When I click on a button I call the PPMPerCountryPerYear function and as you can see I console.log the initialCountries in the beggining BEFORE calling the for loop. On top of that I do not call ANY change on the initialCountries array but the output of the console log is the last updated values even though the for loop hasn't even started. My question is why does this happen and how can I prevent the initialCountries array from changing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'Passed by reference' nature of Javascript is what's giving you trouble here.

That means that in JS if you work with bigger things like, objects {}, arrays [] if you create one based on another like

```
var a = {a: 'a'}
var b = a

a.a='x'

console.log(a.a) // x
console.log(b.a) // x
```

I recommend you place some debugger statements because they are more reliable than console log statements and you'll be surprised with different results

Comment: I made a function to add the objects to the copyData array one by one, this makes the two arrays completely different objects but again when I add a debugger and loop through, I see how the intialCountries array changes every time when updateCurrentData function is called (even though I call it on the copyData array)